# Testing for existence of a properties in JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON ("name" has more members only showing "cinema" here for simplicity)

```
{
    "name": {
        "cinema": {
            "size": {
                "w": 256,
                "h": 200
            },
            "frame": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 256,
                "h": 200
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Which has been parsed using `JSON.parse` and stored in the varable  `bts_json`. I want to loop through each member of "name" and detect if it has the member "frame". Below is my code, I get nothing printed on the console.

```
buildingNames = bts_json.name;

for (buildingFrame in buildingNames) {
   if (buildingFrame.hasOwnProperty("frame")) {
          console.log('exists');
          console.log(buildingFrame["frame"]["y"]);
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You might want a `var` in that `for...in` statement. `for (var buildingFrame in buildingNames) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get the `object`, but the `property name` in `buildingFrame`, so you need to make it work like

```
if (buildingNames[ buildingFrame ].hasOwnProperty("frame")) {
}
```